# QtCreator performance on Windows

Tags: c++, qt4

I've finally managed to run the QtCreator debugger on Windows after struggling with the Comodo Firewall incompatibilities.

I was hoping to switch from an older version of Qt and Visual C++ to the newest version of Qt and QtCreator, but the debugger performance is atrocious.

I have created a simple GUI with one window that does nothing else but display the window. After starting up QtCreator takes ~60MB RAM (Private bytes in Sysinternals process explorer).

When I start debugging, GDB is using 180MB. I start examining the main window pointer and it jumps to 313. Every time I try to inspect something, one of the cores jumps to 100% use and I have to wait for a few seconds for the information to show. This is just a toy program and I'm afraid that the real program that I want to switch will be much worse.

Is this kind of performance normal for MinGW? Would changing to the latest MinGW release improve things?

Visual C++ IDE + debugger + real-world program takes just close to 100MB of RAM and examining local variables is instantaneous.

Comment: I think you should submit a bug report at http://www.qtsoftware.com/developer/task-tracker and see what does Qt Software have to say about this. I can't confirm since I mostly use it under Linux.

Comment: How much memory does it use on Linux? Is it lagging there too?

Comment: under Linux qtcreator is taking roughly about 30 MB, the default Qt GUI Application template app is taking up 2 MB when running, and as far as i can tell, gdb is taking about 30 MB.

Comment: I've managed to port the initial project and the memory usage figures are similar to the ones of the toy project.

I'll try to contact the folks at Qt anyway and see what they say about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesterday I built a copy of the Qt 4.5.2 libraries using MSVC 2008 and am using the QtCreator 1.2 MS CDB (Microsoft Console Debugger) support.  It seems much faster than gdb.  Building Qt for MSVC takes a few hours, but it might be worth trying.

Also, that means smaller Qt DLLs and EXEs as the MS compiler/linker is *much* better at removing unused code.  Some of the Qt DLLs are less than half the size of their MinGW equivalents.  Rumour has it that the C++ code the MS compiler generates is faster too.

Comment: Intel Compiler seams to be the faster one. MSVC produces the smaller size libraries. 

http://www.formortals.com/build-qt-static-small-microsoft-intel-gcc-compiler/

Answer (score 1):

I had to work with QtCreator a month ago. It's performance is awful, after 30 minutes of working with him, it will start to respond very slowly to everything. Maybe it's because it's still at the beginning.